# Python Find Duplicate with Note String Preservation

Tags: python, regex

Input looks like this:

```
assign (resid 3 and name H ) (resid 18 and name H ) 2.5 2.5 2.5 ! note string 1
assign (resid 16 and name H ) (resid 5 and name H ) 2.5 2.5 2.5 ! note string 2
assign (resid 42 and name H ) (resid 55 and name H ) 2.5 2.5 2.5 ! note string 3
assign (resid 44 and name H ) (resid 53 and name H ) 2.5 2.5 2.5 ! note string 4
assign (resid 53 and name H ) (resid 44 and name H ) 2.5 2.5 2.5 ! note string 5
```

If you take note here, row 4 are 5 are duplicates here just `(resid 44 and name H )` and `(resid 53 and name H )` are switched. My ideal output would return something like this:

```
assign (resid 3 and name H ) (resid 18 and name H ) 2.5 2.5 2.5 ! note string 1
assign (resid 16 and name H ) (resid 5 and name H ) 2.5 2.5 2.5 ! note string 2
assign (resid 42 and name H ) (resid 55 and name H ) 2.5 2.5 2.5 ! note string 3
assign (resid 44 and name H ) (resid 53 and name H ) 2.5 2.5 2.5 ! DUPLICATE ! note string 4 ! note string 5
```

---

So I have gotten started with the typical way of reading a file in python.

```
txt = open(filename)

print ( lines[0] )
```

I obviously need to capture the strings between `(` and `)` and then do some type of search. I captured those with regex, which was kids stuff. My idea was to use `match[0]` and `match[1]` within a nested loop and do a search. My failed attempt is:

```
for i in lines:
#   match = re.search("\\(.*?\\)", i)
    match = re.findall('\\(.*?\\)',i)
    for x in i:
        mm = re.search("match[0] match[1]", lines)
        print ( mm )
```

`match[0]` and `match[1]` give me what I want if I print them. What is the best way to do this search so I could preserve and transfer the note flag? I imaging that adding `DUPLICATE` to the note string would be trivial.

I'm really only interested in a python solution. I also need to use this for a 400 line program I have been writing.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Someone who is more proficient using regex can maybe point you to a nicer implementation to get the  key but storing the tuples as keys and reversing to check if it already exists should work:

```
lines = """assign (resid 3 and name H ) (resid 18 and name H ) 2.5 2.5 2.5 ! note string 1
assign (resid 16 and name H ) (resid 5 and name H ) 2.5 2.5 2.5 ! note string 2
assign (resid 42 and name H ) (resid 55 and name H ) 2.5 2.5 2.5 ! note string 3
assign (resid 44 and name H ) (resid 53 and name H ) 2.5 2.5 2.5 ! note string 4
assign (resid 53 and name H ) (resid 44 and name H ) 2.5 2.5 2.5 ! note string 5"""

import re

d = {}

r1 = re.compile(r"(?<=\))\s")
r2 = re.compile(r"\(.*\)")

for line in lines.splitlines():
    key = tuple(r1.split(r2.findall(line)[0]))
    # ("foo","bar") == ("bar","foo") , also check current key is not in d
    if tuple(reversed(key)) not in d and key not in d:
        d[key] = line

pp(list(d.values()))
```

Output:

```
['assign (resid 42 and name H ) (resid 55 and name H ) 2.5 2.5 2.5 ! note '
 'string 3',
 'assign (resid 16 and name H ) (resid 5 and name H ) 2.5 2.5 2.5 ! note '
 'string 2',
 'assign (resid 3 and name H ) (resid 18 and name H ) 2.5 2.5 2.5 ! note '
 'string 1',
 'assign (resid 44 and name H ) (resid 53 and name H ) 2.5 2.5 2.5 ! note '
 'string 4']
```

If order matters use a `collections.Ordereddict`. I am not sure what exactly  you want to add to the string but this will add `DUPLICATE ! string 5` etc.. to the existing key value:

```
from collections import OrderedDict

d = OrderedDict()
import re

r1 = re.compile(r"(?<=\))\s")
r2 = re.compile(r"\(.*\)")
for line in lines.splitlines():
    key = tuple(r1.split(r2.findall(line)[0])) 
      # (resid 44 and name H ) (resid 53 and name H ) ->  (resid 53 and name H ) (resid 44 and name H )   
    rev_k = tuple(reversed(key))
    if rev_k in d:
        d[rev_k] += " DUPLICATE " + " ".join(line.rsplit(None,4)[1:])
    elif key in d:
        d[key] += " DUPLICATE " + " ".join(line.rsplit(None,4)[1:])
    else:
        d[key] = line
```

Output:

```
['assign (resid 3 and name H ) (resid 18 and name H ) 2.5 2.5 2.5 ! note '
 'string 1',
 'assign (resid 16 and name H ) (resid 5 and name H ) 2.5 2.5 2.5 ! note '
 'string 2',
 'assign (resid 42 and name H ) (resid 55 and name H ) 2.5 2.5 2.5 ! note '
 'string 3',
 'assign (resid 44 and name H ) (resid 53 and name H ) 2.5 2.5 2.5 ! note '
 'string 4 DUPLICATE ! string 5']
```

depending on what you want to do you could append the original line and the  `DUPLICATE ! string ...` each time so the original string before we saw a dup would be the first element and the rest would be all the `DUPLICATE ! string ...`:

```
lines = """assign (resid 3 and name H ) (resid 18 and name H ) 2.5 2.5 2.5 ! note string 1
assign (resid 16 and name H ) (resid 5 and name H ) 2.5 2.5 2.5 ! note string 2
assign (resid 42 and name H ) (resid 55 and name H ) 2.5 2.5 2.5 ! note string 3
assign (resid 44 and name H ) (resid 53 and name H ) 2.5 2.5 2.5 ! note string 4
assign (resid 53 and name H ) (resid 44 and name H ) 2.5 2.5 2.5 ! note string 5
assign (resid 53 and name H ) (resid 44 and name H ) 2.5 2.5 2.5 ! note string 6"""

from collections import defaultdict


d = defaultdict(list)
r1 = re.compile(r"(?<=\))\s")
r2 = re.compile(r"\(.*\)")

for line in lines.splitlines():
    key = tuple(r1.split(r2.findall(line)[0]))
    rev_k = tuple(reversed(key))
    if rev_k in d:
        d[rev_k].append(line + " DUPLICATE " + " ".join(line.rsplit(None,4)[1:]))
    elif key in d:
            d[key] += " DUPLICATE " + " ".join(line.rsplit(None,4)[1:])
    else:
        d[key].append(line)


    pp(list(d.values()))
```

Output:

```
[['assign (resid 3 and name H ) (resid 18 and name H ) 2.5 2.5 2.5 ! note '
  'string 1'],
 ['assign (resid 44 and name H ) (resid 53 and name H ) 2.5 2.5 2.5 ! note '
  'string 4',
  'assign (resid 53 and name H ) (resid 44 and name H ) 2.5 2.5 2.5 ! note '
  'string 5 DUPLICATE ! note string 5',
  'assign (resid 53 and name H ) (resid 44 and name H ) 2.5 2.5 2.5 ! note '
  'string 6 DUPLICATE ! note string 6'],
 ['assign (resid 42 and name H ) (resid 55 and name H ) 2.5 2.5 2.5 ! note '
  'string 3'],
 ['assign (resid 16 and name H ) (resid 5 and name H ) 2.5 2.5 2.5 ! note '
  'string 2']]
```

Comment: What you have do could be done more simpler but how you know that what line would be contain the `DUPLICATE ` ?  (`DUPLICATE ! note string 4 ! note string 5`) you just wrote `note` at the end of lines as its the hard part of the problem :D

Comment: can you try this string and give me the result?`assign (resid 3 and name H ) (resid 18 and name H ) 2.5 2.5 2.5 ! note string 1
assign (resid 16 and name H ) (resid 5 and name H ) 2.5 2.5 2.5 ! note string 2
assign (resid 5 and name H ) (resid 16 and name H ) 2.5 2.5 2.5 ! note string 3
assign (resid 16 and name H ) (resid 5 and name H ) 2.5 2.5 2.5 ! note string 4
assign (resid 57 and name H ) (resid 44 and name H ) 2.5 2.5 2.5 ! note string 5`

Comment: And for find the duplicate after extract the string between `()` just use `sorted`!

Comment: @Its not for access the previous key, as there is no need to access to previous key at all! because its possible that you have a duplicated line x line later or after! with sorted after extract the 2 sentence in `()` you can join and compare! or you can convert to `tuple` and use `set` to get the unique lines!

Comment: @Kasra, you do realise `sorted("foo 21") == sorted("foo 12")` is True? Also you do need to  the key of you want to keep adding the the original string. You also cannot use a set. The whole point of my code is that  you can have duplicate later so I have no idea what you are saying with *because its possible that you have a duplicated line x line later or after*

Comment: Thank you very much for a great answer that I can follow. Would you mind showing how you printed the output in the second example? I hate to admit that I need help with the printing.

Comment: @PhysicalChemist, no prob you're welcome. That is the pprint library, it formats the output automatically. There are a few examples in the docs. https://docs.python.org/2/library/pprint.html Also maybe storing each dup in a list of values for each key might be another approach to take.

Comment: One more thing, do you have any advice for dealing with a note string that contains  `(` and `)`? I thought I could just change the regex from `(?<=\))\s` to `(?<=\))(\s)(?=.*\!)`, but that did not work out for me.

Comment: can you add an example?

Answer (score 0):

Building simple dictionary (or [`OrderedDict`](https://docs.python.org/3.2/library/collections.html#ordereddict-objects)) with sorted values as key and whole line (or note) as the value.

Let's assume that this is what you want to be unique:

```
>>> re.findall("\(.*?\)", lns[3])
['(resid 44 and name H )', '(resid 53 and name H )']
```

So you can prepare sorted key:

```
>>> tmp1 = set(re.findall("\(.*?\)", lns[3])) # Line 4
>>> tmp2 = set(re.findall("\(.*?\)", lns[4])) # Line 5
>>> tmp1
{'(resid 44 and name H )', '(resid 53 and name H )'}
>>> tmp2
{'(resid 44 and name H )', '(resid 53 and name H )'}
>>> tmp1 == tmp2
```

But `set` is *unhashable* so you have to convert it to for example `tuple` so it would be usable as [key for dictionary](https://docs.python.org/3.2/library/stdtypes.html#mapping-types-dict):

> A dictionary’s keys are almost arbitrary values. Values that are not hashable, that is, values containing lists, dictionaries or other mutable types (that are compared by value rather than by object identity) may not be used as keys.

```
key = tuple(set((re.findall("\(.*?\)", lns[3]))))
```

Not you just have to store the line and perhaps count of keys?

```
result = {}

with open(filename, 'r') as file:
    for line in file:
        key = tuple(set((re.findall("\(.*?\)", line))))

        if key in result:
            result[key][3] += 1
        else:
            result[key] = [line.strip(), 1]

for line, count in result.values():
    print('Seen line', line, count, 'times')
```

Or store every line with the key:

```
result = collections.defaultdict(list)

# ...
        key = tuple(set((re.findall("\(.*?\)", line))))

        result[key].append(line.strip())

# And nice printing
for key, lines in result.items():
    print('Seen', key, 'on following lines:')
    for l in lines:
        print('\t', l)
    print()
```